# Volume up/down for a specific web browser tab

Tags: audio, web-browser, chrome

I am looking for any application that can change the volume of a specific tab of a web browser.

I do know a Chrome extension that can completely mute a tab but do not know anything that changes the volume of it.

Comment: You're unlikely to be able to intercept the audio stream before it leaves the app. Even the most sophisticated apps which can intercept at any point along the audio chain can't do that. e.g [Audio Hijack](https://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/) or [Loopback](https://rogueamoeba.com/loopback/)

Comment: @Tetsujin: A Chrome extension lives inside the app, though, so it _might_ be possible?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul - it *might* be, I suppose, depending on how it's constructed internally. On Safari you can mute audio in one or more single tabs natively - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pogtw.jpg -  but any intercept of the audio stream can only be done as it exits the app.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of extensions like that for many browsers and they're very easy to find if you just google e.g. "Chrome tab volume". In Chrome I'm using Volume Master which is the 1st result. In Opera it's  e.g. Volume up.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Ubuntu Linux, you can do so on the Operating System level. In Settings/Sound/Volume Levels, all tabs of browsers (with active sound playback) have their individual sound level. You can also completely mute a tab from there.

[image: Sound volume of browser tabs]